# How to release different versions of an Android App in different tracks testing tracks on Play Store

Tags: android, react-native, google-play

I have created a `beta` and 2 closed tracks (`alpha` + `security`) on the play google console site, each track has a different version of our app.

The problem I'm having is that all those tracks point to the same **opt-in*** url, so users only get the same version  (staging) of the app, while I would like for each of them to get a different version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users will get whichever track they are assigned to. They cannot get more than one version at once. It doesn't matter that the opt-in URL is the same, they will get whatever track you assign them to.

If a user is assigned and opted in to more than one track, they will get the APK with the highest version code. But you should avoid this by only assigning individual users to one track.

[Instructions are here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213)